# Exclude files in ant build

Tags: java, ant

I have the following ant file,

```
<project>
<path id="build-classpath">
    <fileset dir="/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="../../lib">
       <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="../../bin">
       <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<target name="compile">
  <mkdir dir="classes"/>
  <mkdir dir="bin"/>
  <javac srcdir="src/" destdir="classes" includeantruntime="false">
    <exclude name="/src/web/DaemonSocket.java"/>
    <classpath refid="build-classpath"/>
  </javac>
  <javac srcdir="src/" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath refid="build-classpath"/>
  </javac>
</target>
 <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="classes"/>
    <delete dir="bin"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

At the exclude line with the code,

```
  <javac srcdir="src/" destdir="classes" includeantruntime="false">
    <exclude name="/src/web/DaemonSocket.java"/>
    <classpath refid="build-classpath"/>
  </javac>
```

I expect the file `DaemonSocket.java` not to be compiled into the `classes` folder. However everytime I run `ant compile`, the `DaemonSocket.java` file is compiled into both the `classes` and the `bin` folder. Why might the `exclude` not be working in this case?

Comment: @DaveNewton https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

Comment: Its a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808612/ant-how-to-use-exclude-excludesfile-with-javac

Comment: @jgr208 Ooo right; forgot it's sort-of inherited :(

Comment: @DaveNewton no worries :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wildcard:

```
  <javac srcdir="src/" destdir="classes" includeantruntime="false">
    <exclude name="**/DaemonSocket.java"/> <!--You should use relative path here /src/ should be removed if you dont want to use wildcard-->
    <classpath refid="build-classpath"/>
  </javac>
```

Comment: thanks, I actually figured that out on my own right after i posted and was waiting to see if someone answered that and you did! Thanks for the help